# no database selected via CGI::SESSION

Tags: database, session, cgi

I'm using CGI:SESSION library.
I'm getting this message while try to set/get data into session table 
mostly using $session->param function

> ***DBD::mysql::db do failed: No database selected at/usr/share/perl5/CGI/Session/Driver/mysql.pm line 50***

I don't have any idea where this came from